# Predict with multiple rows

Tags: r, regression

I want to do a prediction where I will predict using multiple rows. 
Let say my dataset is

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4
R1  4  5  9  8
R2  10 6  3  7
R3  8  7  6  9
R4  9  9  8  10
R5  8  2  7  6
R6  6  5  5  7
...............
...............
R95 7  8  4  6
```

Instead of using:

```
model1 <- lm(X4 ~., data=dataset)
```

How can I manipulate above model to achieve my aim of using R1 to R5 to predict a single value for X4, R6 to R10 to predict another single value for X4 and so on.

Comment: Something like `predict(model, newdata=dataset[1:4,])` and so on.

Comment: Unusual question - it seems highly unlikely that you'd be able to provide any accurate predictions from 45 different models that have been fed with 4 rows each. Assuming the rows have a time series relationship to one another,
we could instead reshape the dataframe to include measurements of X1:X4 over a running window of previous measurements, and then predict the current X4 from those.

Comment: What does the formula look like for your model? Is it something like X4~X1+X2+X3?

Comment: Yes @AndrewJackson  but I want a single value instead of having 5 values for R1 to R5